# Fetch Anchor Discriminator (Typescript)

Tags: anchor, typescript, fetch

How to fetch the anchor discriminator in Typescript?

Answer (score 3):

You can use this function to fetch the Anchor Discriminator in Typescript.

```
function sighash(nameSpace: string, ixName: string): Buffer {
  let name = snakeCase(ixName);
  let preimage = `${nameSpace}:${name}`;
  return Buffer.from(sha256.digest(preimage)).slice(0, 8);
}
```

**Example Instruction**

```
const ixBuffer = sighash('global','initialize')
```